# Write vim log to a file

Tags: vim, gvim, logging

I know that there's a command line option to tell vim (or in my case gVim) to output its own log to a file. Unfortunately I can't remember it. Can anybody help?

Comment: What do you mean by "its own log"?  You can send debug information to a file, but I don't know of any way to log keystrokes, for example, except to record a macro.

Comment: The log contains messages from processing the vimrc file, where it searches for vim files and which files are executed during startup.

Comment: Mostly the same question on stack overflow: [Is there a "vim runtime log"? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025615/is-there-a-vim-runtime-log)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the "verbose" option that can be set on startup:

```
-V[N]       Verbose.  Sets the 'verbose' option to [N] (default: 10).
        Messages will be given for each file that is ":source"d and
        for reading or writing a viminfo file.  Can be used to find
        out what is happening upon startup and exit.  {not in Vi}
        Example: >
            vim -V8 foobar

-V[N]{filename}
        Like -V and set 'verbosefile' to {filename}.  The result is
        that messages are not displayed but written to the file
        {filename}.  {filename} must not start with a digit.
        Example: >
            vim -V20vimlog foobar
```